# Windows Service versus API

Tags: winforms, windows-services

Can anyone tell me the difference between a Windows Service and API?

Comment: References? Windows Services (I assume you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) and API (Application Programming Interface) are not related to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very odd question which leads me to suspect its not actually the one you want to ask...

API is Application Progammer Interface or thereabouts - as generically as possible, its a means for a developer to interface with something by means of software (the something could be another application e.g. Word, or a Web Service or the operating system or a bit of hardware).

A Windows Service is an application that runs in a particular manner on the Windows OS - very roughly - an application without an explicit UI running "in the background" launched when the OS launches (usually, but not necessarily) and independent of logged on users.

So you're comparing a particular type of application with a means of communicating between/with applications?